# Error :The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit

Tags: solidity, blockchain, private-blockchain, smart-contract

I am trying to deploy my contract on sepolia test network .I have 2.1192 sepolia test eth . Everytime I try to deploy the contract I got the same error . saying :

> > The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.

I tried many solutions from the answer with the same title. I tried put maximum gas limit for my contract . I check my solc version . I tried optimize the contract (the contract is too small to optimize.
I have getting stuck with this error over past couple days .dont want to quite .Thanks a lot

here is my deploy.js file

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

const Web3 = require('web3');

const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
   // here I did put my metamask account phrase 
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: '0x0' + bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there'] })
        .send({ gas: "1000000", from: accounts[0] });

    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);

};
deploy();
```

here is my main contract file

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.26;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory intialmsg) public{
        message = intialmsg;
    }

    function setmessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

here is my compile.js file

```
const path= require('path');
const fs= require('fs');

const solc=require('solc');



const inboxPath=path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Inbox.sol');

const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf-8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];
console.log( solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox']);
```

my package .json file

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^4.6.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.26",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  }
}
```

Comment: The gas parameter is probably unrequired.

Comment: You are using really old version of solc and web3. You should upgrade.